# Javascript - Creating a function to encapsulate the statements for swapping the source files for the two image elements?

Tags: javascript, function, swap

So I am starting with this -

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- swap.html                                      Dave Reed -->
<!-- Web page that swaps two images at the click of a button. -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->

<html>
<head>
<title>Image Swapper</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
 <h2>Image Swapper</h2>
 <p>
   <img id="leftImg" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/happy.gif">
   <img id="rightImg" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/sad.gif">
 </p>
 <input type="button" value="Swap images"
        onclick="saved=document.getElementById('leftImg').src;
                 document.getElementById('leftImg').src=
                     document.getElementById('rightImg').src;
                 document.getElementById('rightImg').src=saved;">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And I need to create a function that does the same thing as above, but I don't know where to start or even how to proceed? Any help is appreciated greatly

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no effort has been made by the asker.

Comment: If you want to do what's allready been done, then whats wrong with the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Swapper</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
 <h2>Image Swapper</h2>
 <p>
   <img id="leftImg" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/happy.gif">
   <img id="rightImg" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/sad.gif">
 </p>
 <input type="button" value="Swap images" onClick="swap()">
 </div>
 <script>
    function swap(){
      var saved=document.getElementById('leftImg').src;
      document.getElementById('leftImg').src = document.getElementById('rightImg').src;
      document.getElementById('rightImg').src= saved;
    }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Add a `<script></script>` tag with `function swap(){}` inside, then swap the onClick contents with the function call.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Kudos friend. One more thing however, I now need to add a 3rd image called "surprised.gif" and need to modify the page to rotate the 3 images left and right. I have a button labeled "Rotate Left" and next to it a button labeled "Rotate Right" now I just need to modify the function to act accordingly, would I just add in <img id="middleImg" src="http://balance3e.com/Images/surprised.gif"> inside the <p> tags  as well as document.getElementById('middleImg').src to the function?

Comment: Yea, that sounds exactly right. But you would need two separate functions or add a parameter to the function so that it knows which way to rotate....

Answer (score 0):

At first analyze the logic and behavior of the code. It's all held in English, so if you carefully read it from left to right, things should be understandable (if not clear). Let's try.

The important part is what is happening within the `onclick` attribute of the `<button>` element in your posted HTML. You could, for instance, identify that the code has to be somewhere around the button by loading the HTML file in your browser and checking out where something happens if you click.

Let's beautify the code within the `onclick` attribute:

```
saved                                   = document.getElementById('leftImg').src;
document.getElementById('leftImg').src  = document.getElementById('rightImg').src;
document.getElementById('rightImg').src = saved;
```

As you can see, a variable with the name `saved` is created and the `src` attribute of the element with the ID `leftImg` (within the document) is stored in it. Then the `src` attribute of `rightImg` is stored in `leftImg` and finally `saved` is assigned again to `rightImg`.

If you start with your function, that's what you want. Here's a scaffold to get you started.

```
/**
 * Swap the source of two images within the DOM.
 *
 * @param {String} leftImage The ID of the left image.
 * @param {String} rightImage The ID of the right image.
 */
function swapImages(leftImage, rightImage) {
    var saved;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually understand it now. But I now need to add a 3rd image called "surprised.gif" and need to modify the page to rotate the 3 images left and right. I modified the onclick to "Rotate Left" and created a new onclick called "Rotate Right" now I just need to modify the function to act accordingly, would I just add in <img id="middleImg" src="balance3e.com/Images/surprised.gif">; inside the <p> tags as well as document.getElementById('middleImg').src to the function?